# Average number of PTO days provided by small business in the San Francisco Bay Area

Tags: new-job, united-states

For small businesses in the San Francisco Bay area, what would be the average number of PTO days ([paid time off/personal time off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paid_time_off)) provided for employees?

Are there any reports by payroll or small business organizations?

Comment: Hi Serena.  Although it appears Jane S has done the work for you, we aren't here in replacement of Google.  Questions like this are off topic, so voting to close.

Comment: Also the average number is not the same as the minimum legally required number.

Comment: Statistically an average is not a good choice when looking for information like this since many jobs provide no PTO and it would lower the average rather drastically. The Mode is probably a better number for you as that is the number that occurs most frequently.  And you should probably took at the specific professions you are interested in rather than all. You wouldn't want the numbers for retail (where there is often no leave) to lower the number that you might see for accounting or for computer programming.

Answer (score 5):

Just to convert my comment to an answer (as this appears to be an answerable question, [not a request for legal advice](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3283/33698)), a quick Google search turned up the [San Francisco Office of Labor Standards](http://sfgsa.org/index.aspx?page=430).

If you go through this in detail, it should be able to answer all your questions, or at least give you a contact organisation to ask.